# Azure Function app crashing after 30 minutes

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-function-app

I'm working on an Azure Function App. I was running it, and after **30 minutes** it just stopped working.

It did not throw any exception. (The `try-catch` in the `Run` function did not catch any).

I'm using `App Service Plan - Standard Plan`.
Function App Version: `2`

Am I missing anything here. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "stopped working"? What type of function(what bindings etc.) Do you have a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default timeout of azure function with app service plan is 30 minutes, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#timeout) or the screenshot below:
[image]

You can change it to unbounded execution by editing the host.json, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) (also post the screenshot below for your reference)
[image]

Hope it would be helpful to your problem~